# Exoplayer get chapters of file

Tags: android, exoplayer, id3

I want the id3 chapter data of a playing file in exoplayer (https://id3.org/id3v2-chapters-1.0)

in MPV the chapers are displayed in the videoplayer like so [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeUZT.png)

I beleve that [Chapterframe](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/8a0d52be4b5402af0987fc7d009bc49977c72b67/library/common/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/metadata/id3/ChapterFrame.java) this is what I am looking for

In libvlc you can get this information from [FullChapterDescriptions()](https://github.com/videolan/libvlcsharp/blob/467891c4e31471348424efdc26971cef4e3213b3/src/LibVLCSharp/Shared/MediaPlayer.cs#L1455)

but I dont see any way to get Chapterframe from exoplayer. Everywhere I look they extract metadata from onTracksChanged and run nested for loop untill it looks something like this

```
trackSelections.get(i).getFormat(j).metadata.get(k)
```

BUT this doesn't give ANY metadata on the chapters of the file

How exactly do you get Chapterframe or anything similar to an id3 chapter in android exoplayer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Player.currentStaticMetadata` to get a `List<Metadata>`. Filter out the entries that are instances of `ChapterFrame`. To get the title of the chapter, each `ChapterFrame` should have a subframe (use `Id3Frame.getSubFrame`) that is a `TextInformationFrame`.